# insert N city and get value distance start point to destination point

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3

hello anyone can you give me opinion 
i have some trouble logic to get a distance inter city

example : i give 1 paramater (paramater is name a city from txt)

if i insert city like

'Bali - Jakarta - Jogja - Semarang - Solo '

i can calculate distance from Bali + Jakarta + Jogja + Semarang + Solo

Example

1. Bali --> Jakarta = 480 KM
2. Jakarta --> Jogja = 1202 KM
3. Jogja --> Semarang = 432 KM
4. Semarang --> Solo = 202 KM

so i hope return value is sum from 4 city and show start point to destination point is distance  : 2316 KM

i get distance from json google matrix json

my code so far is :

```
    public function addJarak1($kota) 
    {
       $kota1=$kota;
       $kota2=$kota;
       foreach ($kota1 as $key1 => $value1)
       {
           foreach ($kota2 as $key2 => $value2)
           {

            $berangkat = urlencode($value1);
            $tujuankota = urlencode($value2);

            $data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$berangkat&destinations=$tujuankota&language=id&units=metric&sensor=true");
            $data = json_decode($data);

         //       echo "<pre>". print_r($data ,true) ."</pre>";
            $jarak = 0;

            foreach ($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) 
            {
                $jarak += $road->distance->text;
            }
            $this->simpanjarak1=$jarak;
            //echo "Berangkat: " . $data->origin_addresses[0]+"<br \>Tujuan : " . $data->destination_addresses[0]+"<br \>Jarak: " . $jarak . " KM<br \><br \>";
            return $this->simpanjarak1;

        }
       }
    }




    public function hitungKM ($kota)
    {
        $this->addJarak1($kota);
        $jarak = $this->simpanjarak1;
            if ($jarak != 0 )
            {
                {
                    $jarak ;
                } 
                if($jarak == 1)
                {
                    $jarak = 0;
                } 
            }
            else
            {
                $jarak=0;
            }
            $x= $jarak;
            $x += $jarak;

            echo $jarak;
            return $jarak;

    }


    $kota= Bali + Jakarta + Jogja + Semarang + Solo
    $algo->hitungKM($kota);
```

so if return value is 2316 KM

any one can you give me some ideas ? 
Thank youu 
sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help:

```
print calculate_distance_between_two_uk_cities('birmingham', 'sheffield');

function calculate_distance_between_two_uk_cities($origin, $destination)
{
    $google_matrix_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='
        . urlencode($origin) . ',UK'
        . '&destinations='
        . urlencode($destination) . ',UK'
        . '&language=en&units=imperial';

    $json = file_get_contents($google_matrix_url);

    var_dump($json);

    if($json === false) {
        throw new Exception('Failed to retrieve response.');
    }
    $result = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    if($result === null) {
        throw new Exception('Could not decode JSON response.');
    }
    if(! isset($result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'])) {
        throw new Exception('Could not retrieve distance from remote service.');
    }
    $distance = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
    $distance = intval($distance);

    return $distance;
}
```

I added the UK postfix to the origin and destination, otherwise a lookup like 'birmingham' fails.